# multiple selects on one table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called list and i have to extract the following.
fields are id and date

1. If date<20120401 then count on id >>>> give result
2. If date>20120401 then count on id >>>> give result

if there are 20 items of date<20120401 and 30 items of date>20120401 of an idnumber xyz

then the result should be...

xyz 20 30

I have done like ...

```
select 
 (select count(id) from list where id='xyz' and date<20120401) as date1,
 (select count(id) from list where id='xyz' and date>20120401) as date2;
```

the result is 20 30

but how to print the idnumber?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
id,
SUM(CASE WHEN date < 20120401 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date1,
SUM(CASE WHEN date > 20120401 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date2,
FROM list
WHERE id = 'xyz'
GROUP BY id
```

UPDATE:

```
SELECT
list.id,
idmaster.idlocation,
SUM(CASE WHEN list.date < 20120401 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date1,
SUM(CASE WHEN list.date > 20120401 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date2,
FROM list
INNER JOIN idmaster ON list.id = idmaster.idnumber
WHERE list.id = 'xyz'
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: thank you it worked... one more query on the same... If I have a one more table named idmaster and i have have to select the records of id number of an idlocation from list table.... how to change the query. I mean to say....   select id from idmaster where idlocation='abc' (the above given query) ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Are those tables connected?

Comment: Again, I don't know, what you're after. You need information from table idmaster based on results of query from above? How are the tables connected? Would be best you posted another question, show the tables and the output you expect. And if my answer here helped you, accept my answer please by clicking the green check left to my answer.

Comment: i have done the green..  Yeah the both tables are connected with idnumber. My query is, the idmaster table is having idlocation and idnumber fields and the table2 i.e., list table contains idnumber and date.  Here what I am checking I give the Id location and checking the idnumber of that location from idmaster table. Then the list table should give results of idnumber taken from  idmaster table. Thank you.

Comment: ? You clicked the green check? Accidently clicked twice? Answer is not accepted. I will have a look at your question again tomorrow, if I have the time. Gotta go now.

Comment: @user2059160 Just a second, I think I get what you mean.

Comment: @user2059160 Updated my answer. Change column names accordingly, having just your text and no `CREATE TABLE` statement makes this a bit confusing. Again, gotta go now, hope I could help.

Comment: @nag That's when you have in multiple tables columns with the same name. Write the table name or the alias in front of it, like `WHERE list.id = 'xyz'`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select id, count(id) from list where id='xyz' and date < 20120401
union
select id, count(id) from list where id='xyz' and date > 20120401
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `GROUP BY` clause and maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    l2.id,
    (SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM list l1
    WHERE l1.id = l2.id AND date < 20120401) AS date1,
    (SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM list l1
    WHERE l1.id = l2.id AND date > 20120401) AS date2
FROM
    list l2
GROUP BY
    l2.id
```

There are more cost effective methods to get desired result, but this is the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT
    id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date < 20120401 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date > 20120401 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date2,
    FROM list
    WHERE id = 'xyz'
    GROUP BY id
```